# Filter media library items by size

Tags: filters, media-library, media-modal

I want to prevent users from being able to set a Featured Image from the media library if its width is less than 100px. Originally I thought to use the `ajax_query_attachments_args` filter, but it filters a `WP_Query()` object which effectively cannot be used for this purpose because the `meta_query`'s `meta_key`—which is `_wp_attachment_metadata`—contains serialized data. This is what I'm currently trying:

```
function restrict_media_library_by_width($response, $attachment, $meta) {
  if(isset($response['width']) && isset($response['height']) && $response['width'] >= 100) {
    return $response;
  }
  return false;
}
add_filter('wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'restrict_media_library_by_width', 10, 3);
```

The result I see is that the Media Library modal pops up, loads an "empty" thumbnail, and the AJAX loader continues intermittently appearing and disappearing:

[image]

However, if I change the last conditional in my if statement to use `==` instead of `>=` then it appears to work as expected ***for certain values***:

```
function restrict_media_library_by_width($response, $attachment, $meta) {
  if(isset($response['width']) && isset($response['height']) && $response['width'] == 100) {
    return $response;
  }
  return false;
}
add_filter('wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'restrict_media_library_by_width', 10, 3);
```

It doesn't always work but I suspect I'm missing something here. Can someone please shed some light on this? Thanks!

Comment: You should consider filing a [core ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org). I tested your snippet and got some weird behavior too, that included a blank list item and an infinite request loop. This [#31116 ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31116) might be related, but changing `floor()` to `round()` in `media-models.min.js` didn't fix the issue you describe. We also have to make sure we don't have plugins that are  using this filter, like the ACF. In that case we have to increase the priority number. Otherwise the `array_filter( $posts )` part won't strip out the empty items.

Comment: ps: on another install, I got the blank item in the first image row and infinite request loop, only when I scrolled down to the bottom of the media library, when choosing a featured image.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Bug submitted as [#31570](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31570).

Answer (score 2):

So far, the only workable solution I've come up with is to run a new query within the `ajax_query_attachments_args` filter.

It's definitely not ideal but works as expected in the absence of a more efficient alternative:

```
function restrict_media_library_by_width($query) {
  $include = array();
  $exclude = array();
  $temp_query = new WP_Query($query);
  if($temp_query->have_posts()) {
    while($temp_query->have_posts()) {
      $temp_query->the_post();
      $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata(get_the_ID());
      $meta['mime-type'] = get_post_mime_type(get_the_ID());
      if(isset($meta['mime-type']) &&
        ($meta['mime-type'] == 'image/jpeg' && isset($meta['width']) && $meta['width'] >= 100) ||
         $meta['mime-type'] == 'image/svg+xml') {
        $include[] = get_the_ID();
      } else {
        $exclude[] = get_the_ID();
      }
    }
  }
  wp_reset_query();

  $query['post__in']     = $include;
  $query['post__not_in'] = $exclude;

  return $query;
}
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', 'restrict_media_library_by_width');
```