# Add guid filter to attachment in media library grid mode

Tags: filters, media-modal, backbone, guids

I'm trying to show in media modal box, attachments from a specific folder in my website and, correct me if I'm wrong, the best way to proceed is a like filter on `wp_posts` field GUID. Something like `and ({$wpdb->posts}.guid LIKE '%/uploads_media_news/%'))`.

[image: wp_postsGUID]

Problem is I don't really know where to apply this filter: is it better to act on `backbone.js`? On a `.php` file, perhaps `ajax-actions.php`?

I don't really know what to do anymore, I've been working on this change for 3 days with no result.

Comment: I think I'm moving closer to a solution: thanks to [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/180540/114036), I modified the function to check if(isset($meta['file']) && strpos($meta['file'], 'media_news') !== FALSE). The problem now is .png images wont show.